# Does uber have an API which let user download invoice pdf?

Tags: python, uber-api

I have been searching for a way to get my past ride invoice. Is there any api which i can use to get my rides info/invoice. as i don't want to click on every ride and then. Just want to automate the boring stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Does uber have an API which let user download invoice pdf?" - No, that API does not exist.